# Double while loop with sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

I created a code that is working fine but I'm not sure if its 'legit'.
I am using a sql query in a while loop from another sql query, that means that the (second) sql query is repeated the amount of rows the first query returns.

Can anyone tell me if I can use this or its just one complete mess?

the code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql_feat = 'SELECT * FROM wp_wpl_dbst WHERE category = 105';
$result_feat = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_feat);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result_feat) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_feat)) {

        $filter_feat = $row["table_column"];
        $filter_name = $row["name"];

        $sql_feat2 = 'SELECT * FROM wp_wpl_properties';
        $result_feat2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_feat2);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_feat2) > 0) {

            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_feat2)) {

                if (!empty($row2[$filter_feat])) {
                    echo $filter_name;
                    echo "<br>";                                         
                } 
            }
        }                                                          
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you execute the inner sql query multiple times. It does not change, so you are guaranteed to get the same result each time, since no update or insert is done in between. That means it is enough to execute the query and fetch the result set a single time, outside the loops.

Comment: What is the association between the 2 queries? Maybe left join with `table_column`..

Comment: @chris85 The first querie checks what table column must be used for the second while loop

Comment: @ThomasBeumer Can you post some sample rows from each table? I'm not exactly sure I see how this works yet.

Comment: @arkascha That make sens, Imma get back to you after a tryd. Thanks for the input. Still learning o.o"..

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always check the result of mysqli_query before assuming it represents a proper query result:

```
// you should check if this value is FALSE before using it
$result_feat = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_feat);

// and this too
$result_feat2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_feat2);
```

As for your code running a query inside the loop, it is pretty much always discouraged unless there is no other option. You should explore the possibility of a JOIN before running any queries inside a loop. Cases may exist where you have no other option, but in your code, I don't see any point at all to run this query over and over:

```
$sql_feat2 = 'SELECT * FROM wp_wpl_properties';
```

If it made reference to the value from $row, then *maybe.* But it doesn't.

Comment: True, but a `JOIN` is _not_ always the preferable approach, even _if_ two queries are somehow connected. The issue is the performance. Although such `JOIN`s are exactly the strength of relational database systems that also is exactly the point where queries get _really_slow. Sometimes it is more efficient to use separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are doing dynamic sql so join would not be possible but adding where clause to second select would make it more efficient. something like -  $sql_feat2 = 'SELECT ' + $filter_name + ' FROM wp_wpl_properties where ' + $row2[$filter_feat] + ' is not null';